# Restarting a service of other class, while depending on the other class, creates a dependency cycle

Tags: puppet

In puppet, I have the following two classes:

```
class zabbix-agent {
    package { 'zabbix-agent': }
    ->
    service { 'zabbix-agent':
        ensure => running
    }
}

class zabbix-agent-cassandra {
    include zabbix-agent
    Class['zabbix-agent']
    ->
    file { '/etc/zabbix/zabbix_agent.conf.d/cassandra.conf':
    }
    ~>
    Service['zabbix-agent']
}
```

This looks great at first, since it allows to add new configurations files to /etc/zabbix/zabbix_agent.conf.d/ from any class, and to restart zabbix-agent when doing so.

However there is a dependency cycle:

```
Service[zabbix-agent] => Class[Zabbix-agent] => File[/etc/zabbix/zabbix_agentd.conf.d/cassandra.conf] => Service[zabbix-agent]
```

It there a way to avoid the dependency cycle ?

Answer (score 0):

You're telling Puppet to

- manage the zabbix package and service
- do this before managing the config file
- if the config file changed, manage the service (again)

This is problematic, given that Puppet will touch each resource exactly once.

The best approach will likely be to bring more structure to your zabbix module.

```
class zabbix::agent {
    include zabbix::package
    include zabbix::service
    Class['zabbix::package'] -> Class['zabbix::service']
}
```

This allows you to just

```
Class['zabbix::package'] -> File[...] ~> Class['zabbix::service']
```

which is DRYer and, in your particular case, avoids circular dependencies.

Comment: The file is to be created in a folder created by the zabbix-agent package, so I must ensure that it's installed before managing the file. Then I need to restart the service.

Comment: Sure, you should probably hang on to your `Class['zabbix::package'] -> File[...]`. Should still be no loop. Will edit this into the answer.